# iPhone SDK versions

Tags: iphone

What is the newest iPhone SDK version available for 10.6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS SDK 3.1

iOS SDK 4 requires OS 10.6.2 or later. So no, it won't work for you. It looks like iOS 3.1 would be your best bet, because 3.2 requires 10.6.2 as well.

Comment: Does it really work with 10.6.0 version? I know, there is 10.6.4 update available but I cannot update for now.

Comment: I would assume so, although I'm sure you can find slightly older versions of the SDK elsewhere if it does not work for you. I guess you should just try it out and see what happens.

Comment: OK, thanks. As far as I remember, I could not install 3.2 because OS was too old.

Comment: I updated my answer, and I'll try to find the latest for 10.6.0

Comment: I'm using 3.1.2 for now, XCode 3.2.

Comment: I'd stick with that, unless you could upgrade only to 10.6.2 and not to 10.6.4 (I'm not familiar with OS X update procedures)

Answer (score 0):

The latest available version is iOS SDK 4.0.1.